# Change or turn off the auto renew cancellation system email

Tags: civimember, auto-renew

I've probably gone round the circle so many times I've missed it's obvious start! However, I can't find the origin of the system email that goes to people when they or the system cancels their auto-renew membership.

It contains the text, "Your auto renew membership sign-up has ended and your membership will not be automatically renewed."

As far as I can see, this is not the System message, 'Memberships - Auto-renew Cancellation Notification', which in our system has a very different text (when viewing the default message as well as our modified message.)

So... where should I look to find this text?

Sorry if this is a totally obvious answer that I've missed... :-)

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like text from the Recurring Start and End notification... did you check there perchance?

Comment: Ah yes! Well spotted. Thanks so much.
Is it possible to completely turn these off somehow?

Comment: I suspect you would have to make that change in the code; there's not a UI option for it as far as I know.  IMHO it's helpful for constituents to know when their gifts/membership dues recurring payments start and end, so perhaps tweaking the language to work for your context might be a better option.